# tcsh scripting : regex in if statement

Tags: tcsh

what is the correct way to code this perl statment in tcsh shell script

foreach (@array) {
    if (/^(pam|pom)/) {
         dosomething();
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

set array = ( foo pam bar pom baz xpam pamx )
alias dosomething echo

foreach elem ($array:q)
    if ($elem:q =~ {pam,pom}*) then
        dosomething $elem:q
    endif
end
```

Note that the expression on the right side of the `=~` operator is a file matching pattern, not a regular expression, so this solution doesn't generalize to all cases.  If you need regular expression matching, you can use the `expr` command:

```
expr STRING : REGEXP
```

or, equivalently:

```
expr match STRING REGEXP
```