# Translation bash to tcsh, if with pattern

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, tcsh

I hava following code in bash:

```
if  [[ $a =~ ^[+-]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)([DdEeQ][+-]?[0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
```

How can I do this in tcsh? I tried:

```
if  ( $a =~ {^[+-]?{[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*\|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+}{[DdEeQ][+-]?[0-9]+}?\$} ) then
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: That's part of `[[`, not `if`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4521799/1030675

Comment: still dont understand. So I cant do that analogously to solution in bash? I should use expr command? Can someone give me example? I'm thinking about that all day. It is very importat to me. Why there are so few resources on the web for tcsh?

Comment: maby the simplest way is using sed

Answer (score 2):

bash natively support regular expressions not tcsh apparently. The expr command can be used instead ; following tests shows that | ( ) ? and + must be escaped to not be taken literally (contrary to perl for example).

To test :

```
expr a : '\(a\|b\)'
expr b : 'a\?b'
expr aab : 'a\+b'
```

and

```
expr "$a" : '^[+-]\?\([0-9]\+\.\?[0-9]*\|[0-9]*\.\?[0-9]\+\)\([DdEeQ][+-]\?[0-9]\+\)\?$'
```

or

```
pattern='^[+-]\?\([0-9]\+\.\?[0-9]*\|[0-9]*\.\?[0-9]\+\)\([DdEeQ][+-]\?[0-9]\+\)\?$'
if expr "$a" : "$pattern" >/dev/null; then
    ..
fi
```